# How does a (halogen) wound transformer dimmer work?

Tags: transformer, triac, dimmer, halogen

I'm replacing a broken halogen dimmer and I noticed that it has inside a wound transformer, but it is connected only to two leads: "input" and dimmed "output".

It also has some more electronic components, but I haven't checked exactly.

I thought that the dimmer required some neutral connection too, to have a reference point for the phase control, so that the TRIAC can cut the waveform when the threshold is reached.

What is the equivalent circuit of a wound transformer dimmer that has only two leads?

Comment: it is a coil, not a transformer

Answer (score 1):

> What is the equivalent circuit of a wound transformer dimmer that has only two leads?

That is a coil or inductor and is a filter to limit the amount of electro-magnetic noise generated by the dimmer.

> I thought that the dimmer required some neutral connection too, to have a reference point for the phase control, so that the TRIAC can cut the waveform when the threshold is reached.

No, they can get a neutral connection through the lamp during the 'off' periods. There are thousands of articles on how dimmers work on the web so I don't think there is much point writing one here.